# C# PDF Delete - File 'being used by another process'

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ioexception, delete-file

I've searched far and wide for an answer to this question. I know WHY I'm received the exception, but I can't for the life of find the cause of it in my code.

Basically, my code creates four separate PDF files, joins them into on big PDF file and then deletes the original four files. Everything words fine, except I receive an IOException when trying to delete the files because they are 'being used by another process.'

Here is the code I use to merge the files:

```
private static Document MergeFiles(string[] fileNames, string finalFileName)
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 25, 25);
    if (fileNames.Length > 0)
    {
        int a = 0;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileNames[a]);
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        FileStream output = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\" + finalFileName, FileMode.Create);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;

        while (a < fileNames.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                doc.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                else
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
            }
            a++;
            if (a < fileNames.Length)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(fileNames[a]);
                n = reader.NumberOfPages;
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Close();
    return doc;
}
```

And here is the code for deleting the files:

```
private static void DeleteFile(string[] fileNames)
{
    if (fileNames != null)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < fileNames.Length; x++)
        {
            if(!fileNames[x].Equals(""))
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileNames[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I presume somewhere in the loop when I'm merging the documents, something isn't being closed (reader/writer) but I've tried lots of different combos and nothing seems to work. It's REALLY starting to annoy me.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your comments, everyone. I've amended my code to this:

```
private static Document MergeFiles(string[] fileNames, string finalFileName)
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 25, 25);
    if (fileNames.Length > 0)
    {
        while (a < fileNames.Length)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileNames[a]))
            using (FileStream output = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\" + finalFileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output))
            {
                int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                doc.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                PdfImportedPage page;
                int rotation;

                int i = 0;
                while (i < n)
                {
                    i++;
                    doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                    doc.NewPage();
                    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                    else
                        cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
                a++;
                if (a < fileNames.Length)
                {
                    n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Close();
    return doc;
}
```

It compiles, but I get an error at runtime which points to the closing brace of the Using loop:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot access a closed file.
```

Comment: Maybe instantiate the PdfReader(fileName[a]) in a using statement?

Comment: A couple of suggestions: Don't return a `Document` object, it doesn't really make sense once you've closed it. Either return a boolean for success, the filename (probably not since you're passing it in) or possibly switch to a `MemoryStream` and return the byte array. If your original four documents are small enough I'd create those each as a `MemoryStream`, too, and just work off of the byte array. This way you don't have to worry about hitting the disk ever.

Comment: Chris, I ended up going with your solution and using a MemorySteam and the byte arrays. It ended up being much faster and much easier, with none of the problems associated with the PdfReaders and such.
Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

You're not disposing *any* of your resources.

`PdfReader`, `PdfWriter`, and `FileStream` all implement `IDisposable`. These all need to either be `Dispose`d or wrapped in a `using` block (preferably the latter).

My guess is it's the `PdfReader` instances that are holding those files open.

P.S. It's not enough to just `Close` them at the end of the method, as that will leave them open "permanently" (or as long as the process runs) if any exceptions occur before those calls execute. Either put your cleanup in a `finally` block or just use `using`.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, Aaron. Are you able to provide a quick example of how I'd instantiate the using statement in this instance? I'm new (as of yesterday!) to the Using statement :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I know the general way to use the statement, but I'm not entire sure how to use it in this instance.
E.g. I've done
'using(PDFReader reader = new PDFReader(fileNames[0]))
{
//code
}'

Except I receive a compile error 'Cannot assign to reader because it is a 'using variable' on this line which is inside the Using block:
'reader = new PdfReader(fileNames[a]);'

Comment: @BennyO'Neill, with respect to your latest edit, try setting `writer.CloseStream = false` before `doc.Close`.

Comment: Hi mate, that didn't work either. I suspect there's an issue in the assembly itself. I made a ton of adjustments with all of your suggestions (and a few others from the MSDN forums) and created a completely workable solution, but an exception kept getting thrown that just did not make any sense.
Anywho, somebody above suggested using a byte array which I have done, and it appears to be working flawlessly now.

Thanks for all your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Although you're closing the document (`doc.Close();`), you're not closing the filestream, writer and reader.

Add this after `doc.Close();`:

```
writer.Close();
output.Close();
reader.Close();
```